# Horizontal alignment in an item in itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I would like to make two columns within an `item` in `itemize`.  Here is an example that I made with -- gasp! -- a word processor:

[image: word processor]

I would like to be able to adjust the "column" widths/"tabs." How can I accomplish this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

List:
\begin{itemize}
  \item{apple fruit}
  \item{cucumber vegetable}
  \item{steak meat}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Why not use a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tabto`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

List:
\begin{itemize}
  \item apple    \tabto{10em} fruit
  \item cucumber \tabto{10em} vegetable
  \item steak    \tabto{10em} meat
\end{itemize}

List:
\begin{itemize}
  \item apple\tabto{10em}fruit
  \item cucumber\tabto{10em}vegetable
  \item steak\tabto{10em}meat
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The second list is just to show that spaces around `\tabto{10em}` are ignored, so the input can be organized to *see* the alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get your desired result by using a `tabularx` environment as part of your `\item`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

List:
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
            apple & fruit
        \end{tabularx}  
    \item 
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
            cucumber & vegetable
        \end{tabularx}
    \item 
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
            steak & meat
        \end{tabularx}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: table as item]

If you don't want the two columns to be spaced out thus far, you could also use a `tabular` environment and use three columns, one of which is the spacing between the two strings. The problem with this method is, that you need to define a fixed width for at least the first and the second column.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

List:
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{10em}p{1em}l}
            apple && fruit
        \end{tabular}  
    \item 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{10em}p{1em}l}
            cucumber && vegetable
        \end{tabular}
    \item 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{10em}p{1em}l}
            steak && meat
        \end{tabular}
    \item 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{10em}p{1em}l}
            a very long entry to sow why the central column is important to have && meat
        \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: table-2]

Answer (score 3):

This version uses `\textbullet` automatically in each line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
List:
\begin{trivlist}% for vertical spacing
\item\begin{tabular}{@{\hbox to \leftmargini{\hfill\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}}ll}
apple&fruit\\
cucumber&vegetable\\
steak&meat
\end{tabular}
\end{trivlist}
\begin{itemize}
\item normal itemize
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

Just use a table. You can match the spacing and style of lists using the appropriate parameters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment*{tabularitemize}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{ @{\hskip\leftmargin\llap{\labelitemi\hskip\labelsep}} #1 }%
}{%
  \end{tabular}\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularitemize}{ l l }
  apple & fruit \\
  cucumber & vegetable \\
  steak & meat \\
\end{tabularitemize}

\begin{itemize}
  \item This is a real list.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Spacing between the rows and columns of the table can be adjusted as usual.

Answer (score 2):

You also can do that either with the `listliketab` package or with a standard itemize and the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

List:

\storestyleof{itemize}
\begin{listliketab}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{Ll@{\qquad}l }
   \textbullet & apple & fruit \\
  \textbullet & cucumber & vegetable \\
   \textbullet & steak & meat
  \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

\begin{itemize}
  \item\eqmakebox[L][l]{apple} fruit
  \item\eqmakebox[L][l]{cucumber\hspace{2em}\null} vegetable
  \item\eqmakebox[L][l]{steak} meat
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]