# Using tabto package in conjunction with nested enumerate and itemize lists

Tags: enumitem, tabto

I am using the [`tabto`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabto/tabto-doc.pdf) package, [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567755/15622). However, I seem to run into difficulties when I try to use `\tabto` in an `itemize` environment that is nested in an `enumerate` environment (via the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item{fruit}\tabto{3.0cm}sweet
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{apple}\tabto{3.0cm}crisp
      \item{banana}\tabto{3.0cm}soft
    \end{itemize}
  \item{vegetable}\tabto{3.0cm}savory
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{carrot}\tabto{3.0cm}crunchy
      \item{cucumber}\tabto{3.0cm}hard as a rock
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
More text.
```

[image: mwe]

I would like "crisp," "soft," "crunchy," etc to align with "fruit" and "vegetable."

I am thinking that the "misalignment" indicates that `tabto` is measuring relative to the indentation of the `itemize` environment. If I could somehow subtract the width of the indentation, I should be able to get the alignment I'm looking for. How should I do this, or should I be using a completely different approach?

(FYI, my thesis is not actually about fruits and vegetables!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item{fruit} \tabto{3.0cm+\leftmargin-\labelwidth-\labelsep-\itemindent} sweet
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{apple} \tabto{3.0cm-\leftmargin} crisp
      \item{banana} \tabto{3.0cm-\leftmargin} soft
    \end{itemize}
  \item{vegetable} \tabto{3.0cm+\leftmargin-\labelwidth-\labelsep-\itemindent} savory
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{carrot} \tabto{3.0cm-\leftmargin} crunchy
      \item{cucumber}\tabto{3.0cm-\leftmargin} hard as a rock
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
More text.

\end{document}
```